# "haben" und "sein" im Präteritum oder im Perfekt

Tags: tense

Bei meinem letzten Unterricht mit einem Muttersprachler habe ich ihn gefragt, ob die Perfekt- oder die Imperfektformen von Verben "haben" und "sein" gebräuchlicher sind, natürlich wenn es um die Vergangeheit geht. Der Muttersprachler, der aus Berlin ist, hat mir gesagt, dass eher die Perfektformen besser klingeln, insbesondere in mündliche Sprache.

Das war für mich etwas ein wenig Überraschendes, da ich eigentlich überzeugt war, dass ausgerechnet diese Verben eher im Präteritum verwendet werden. Ist das vielleicht von dem Region abhängig? Oder vom Alter? Vielleicht spielt hier der Zusammenhang zwischen der Handlung in der Vergangenheit und der Gegenwart auch eine Rolle?

Vielen Dank vorab!

Beste Grüße
Maciej (Polen)

Comment: Es wird zwar gesagt, dass im Schwäbischen (Raum Stuttgart) und Bairischen kein Präteritum existiert.  Dass aber in Berlin für 'sein' und 'haben' (und dann wahrscheinlich auch für die Modalverben) das Perfekt in der gesprochenen Sprache gebräuchlicher wäre als das **Präteritum** (in den Grammatiken heißt das jetzt so), würde mich sehr wundern; in meiner Region (Ruhrgebiet, dem Berlinerischen ziemlich ähnlich) ist das definitiv nicht der Fall, aber wer weiß. Im Prinzip ist es korrekt, dass im Mündlichen bei den angesprochenen Verben das  Präteritum bevorzugt wird oder zumindest sehr häufig ist.

Comment: Wenn ich mal so google, finde ich mit "ick hatte det *" ne ganze Menge (zwar oft Plusquamperfekt, aber nicht nur) und mit "ick hab det * jehabt" jaarnüscht bis uff een Treffer. Aber: "ick bin * jewesen" findet relativ viel, es kann also für Berlin vielleicht doch was dran sein an der Aussage des Muttersprachlers.

Comment: @RalfJoerres Das ist auch keine besonders gute Methode die aktuellen Verhältnisse abzubilden

Comment: @choXer Stimmt. Weißt du eine bessere? Speziell in Sachen Berlinerisch mit Schwerpunkt auf Gebrauchshäufigkeit von Präteritum vs. Perfekt ?

Comment: @RalfJoerres Mir fällt da aktuell nichts zu ein. Ich kenne auch ehrlich gesagt niemanden, der wirkliche berlinert und wohne hier mein Leben lang.

Answer (score 1):

Ich kann nur für Deutsch sprechen, keine Dialekte, bei denen es praktisch beliebige Abweichungen geben kann: Grundsätzlich kommt meiner Erfahrung nach Perfekt in gesprochener Sprache und in direkter Rede etwas häufiger vor, Präteritum wirkt vielleicht eine winzige Spur gestelzter.

Das gilt aber in erster Linie für Nicht-Hilfsverben, also:

> Ich habe gelesen.

statt

> Ich las.

Du sprichst jedoch die Vergangenheitsformen der Hilfsverben selbst an, also "war" und "bin gewesen" für "sein" sowie "hatte" oder "habe gehabt" für "haben". Die Hilfsverben stehen ja eigenständig meist nur als Verben für Partizipien ("Ich bin müde", "ich habe Hunger"), da kommt mir das Perfekt etwas kompliziert vor ("Ich bin müde gewesen", "Ich hatte Hunger gehabt"). **Ich würde Dir hier das Präteritum empfehlen.**

P.S.: +1 für "Klingeln" in Deiner Frage! :)

Comment: Ich stimme mit Nils Magnus völlig überein (einschließlich P.S.).

Answer (score 0):

In (machen Gegenden von) Ostdeutschland ist meiner persönlichen Erfahrung nach das Perfekt, und vor allem das Plusquamperfekt, von *haben* und *sein* deutlich verbreiteter als im Rest von Deutschland (zur Schweiz und Österreich kann ich nichts sagen). »Ich war im Freibad‌.« und »Ich hatte Halsschmerzen.« sind m. E. die in Gesamtdeutschland gängigeren Formen als »Ich bin im Freibad gewesen«/»Ich habe Halsschmerzen gehabt« oder gar »Ich war im Freibad gewesen«/»Ich hatte Halsschmerzen gehabt«.

Je nachdem wie Du gefragt hast kann die Frage auch so (miss)verstanden worden sein, ob Perfekt oder Präteritum allgemein gebräuchlicher sind. Da müsste ich zustimmen, dass Perfekt in der gesprochenen Gesprache deutlich gebräuchlicher ist.